# Сборка проекта на Webpack c несколькими HTML и CSS файлами

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

Можно ли как-то настроить Webpack так, чтобы в dist попали 2 html файла и 2 файла css, при этом каждый css файл подключен к конкретному html? Пока получается собрать все только в один файл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось сделать подключение конкретного css к конкретному html при сборке с помощью добавления 'enty point' для каждого файла и добавлению свойства 'chunks', для каждого из файлов html в HTMLWebpackPlugin, что дает возможность подключить только необходимые чанки, которые соответствуют именам css файлов.

```
new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
  template: './index.html',
  chunks: ['main']
}),
new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
  template: './service.html',
  filename: 'service.html',
  chunks: ['service'],
}),
new CleanWebpackPlugin(),

new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
  filename: '[name].css',
}),
```

Answer (score 1):

Да, в документации все описанно [entry points](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#multi-page-application)
Тоесть у сборки появляется несколько точек входа, общий код кинется в отдельный чанк